# Choosing the right Foregin key in SQLite table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table Details in which _id is the primary key by default. Now while inserting i have to make multiple inserts to different tables. for each record I have to insert one row in Details table and one record in Notifications table this happens one after the other for each record.

Now I am assigning a foreign key to the second table that is Notifications, this is the primary key of details table(Which is auto increment integer) is this the right approach? I wonder how do I extract this primary key of details table as soon as insertion in Details table is made and then supply this _id as the foreign key to my next query which will add row in the notification table.

The second approach I think of would be to assign a different primary key in Details (Which I will supply to the query explicitly), keep a record of this key and use it as a foreign key in Notifications table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

will allow you to pick up the _id used in any previous insertion.

Just make sure this is executed after a Details table insert.

Comment: Thanks Mate, let me try this hands on!